# execute javascript from popup in a caller page

Tags: javascript

i have 2 pages: A.htm and B.htm
A calls B as a popup, then after some operations B must call a javascript inside A, to do this i used the javascript: "opener".

but i think i did some mistakes because in the popup when i click the button nothing happen, here an example to download: [http:\www.suale.it/prova/a.zip](http://http:%5C%5Cwww.suale.it/prova/a.zip)

this is the code of A.htm

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">


            function ricaricapagina() 
            {
                var theform;
                if 
                (
                    window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("netscape") > -1) {
                    theform = document.forms["frmMain"];
                }
                else 
                {
                    theform = document.frmMain;
                }

                //txtOperation.value=pOperation;
                theform.submit();   
            }

            function SelectArticoli(pForm, txtOperation)
            {
                var sQueryString=new String;
                var WinSettings = "center=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=1000";
                sQueryString='B.htm';
                sQueryString += '?CallerForm=' + pForm;   
                sQueryString += '&CallerOperation=' + txtOperation;   
                sQueryString += '&CallerReload=1' ;   

                   window.open(sQueryString, '',  WinSettings);
            }

</script>
<form name="frmMain" id="frmMain" action="A.htm" method="post">
<input name="txtOperation" type="hidden" id="txtOperation" />

<input name="cmdSelectArticoli" id="cmdSelectArticoli" onclick="javascript:SelectArticoli('frmMain', 'txtOperation');" type="button" value="Aggiungi Articoli...">

</form>

</html>
```

this is the code of B.htm

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">

            function chiudipopup(pResult)
            {

                if (pResult==true)
                {

                    window.opener.document.forms[frmMain].item(frmMain.txtCallerOperation.value).value = 'SelectArticoli';                  


                    if (frmMain.txtCallerReload.value != '')
                    {
                        window.opener.ricaricapagina();
                    }
                }

                window.close();
            }

    </script>

</script>
<form name="frmMain" method="post" id="frmMain">
    <input name="txtCallerOperation" type="hidden" id="txtCallerOperation" value="txtOperation" />

  <input type="submit" name="cmdConferma" onclick="javascript:chiudipopup(true);" value="conferma" id="cmdConferma" class="button" />

</form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try declaring the function as window.ricaricapagina = function(){...}

Answer (score 0):

You have two problem:

1. [B.html]=>change `window.opener.document.forms[frmMain].item(frmMain.txtCallerOperation.value).value` to `window.opener.document.forms["frmMain"].elements["txtOperation"].value`
2. [B.html]=>`window.opener.ricaricapagina();`(I'm working on it :))